# Are content scripts in Chrome extensions run in the extension process or the tab process?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Are content scripts in Chrome extensions run in the extension process or the tab process?
I.e. if my extension process in the Chrome task manager is taking up a lot of CPU, is the offending code most likely in the content scripts, or the background page of my extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are run in the tab's process.

Comment: Thanx, that was simple... the docs said they run in their own "isolated world", but didn't mention where this world runs :-)

Comment: Any documentation that cites this?